# Using a shared TableView for 3 of my tabs

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to use the same TableView for 3 of my tabs instead of using 3 identical TableViews. I created three navigation controllers (one for each of the tabs) and linked them to the same Table View Controller But if I run the app with the storyboard like the picture below, it works for the first one of the sharing tabs, but for the other two I get a black screen where the tableView should be. So I want to know if it is even possible to make it work with this setup?

[image]

I'm trying this, so I don't have to make a litte change in the tableview 3 times.. The 3 tabs are populated with the same data too, just filtered differently, so just filter the array depending on which parent navigation controller would be simple I suppose.. But I need to know if this is a possible way of sharing view or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach. Just have three different table views. But since the question is not about being the right approach, I would say that the best way to do it is to do it by code, removing the tableview from the super view (The view controller's view) and moving it to a new view controller when the delegate from the tabbarcontroller is called. Keep in mind that you will also have to assign the delegate and datasource for each view controller.

Comment: Ok screw this I'll use 3 TableViews again and do some repeated cell changing if needed. Thanks :)